# How do I update the attributes of an attribute on an AR model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using [the piggybak gem](http://www.piggybak.org/index.html).

I have a Product `q`:

```
1.9.3p194 :009 > q
 => #<Product id: 20, name: "iPad", description: "<p>\r\n\tiPad 11&quot; tablet that will change the way...", price: 499.0, vendor_id: 11, created_at: "2012-12-15 23:40:27", updated_at: "2013-01-01 00:18:39", image: "ipad.png", sku: "AB-09123">
```

`q` has an attribute `piggybak_sellable` which has other attributes.

```
1.9.3p194 :010 > q.piggybak_sellable
 => nil
```

This is an example of the attributes available to a `Product` that has been assigned in the Rails Admin UI.

```
1.9.3p194 :011 > p.piggybak_sellable
 => #<Piggybak::Sellable id: 1, sku: "AR4590", description: "Blue Shirt", price: #<BigDecimal:7ffa1ba863b8,'0.2499E2',18(45)>, quantity: 100, item_id: 19, item_type: "Product", active: true, unlimited_inventory: false>
```

I would like to add those attributes to a `nil` record.

I would like to update all those attributes of `q.piggybak_sellable` without having to do it manually i.e. setting `q.piggybak_sellable.sku = "ARJHR"`, etc.

I tried doing `update_attributes` and it didn't work:

```
1.9.3p194 :008 > q.piggybak_sellable.update_attributes(:sku => "YJ4567", :description => "Awesome tablet", :price => 399, :quantity => 100, :item_id => 20, :item_type => "Product", :active => true)
NoMethodError: undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass
```

Thoughts on how I can do this?

I am trying to put this in a callback on my `Product` model - for what it's worth.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean that `piggybak_sellable` is an association (i.e. another model)?

Comment: Well, I am using the `piggybak` gem - which is a Rails engine. I haven't explicitly created another model and setup an association - but there may be an assocation created by the gem. So, I can't go into another model and set up anything like that - if that is what you are thinking...but strictly speaking, yes...you may be right.

Comment: Oh sorry, I wasn't aware of that gem.

Comment: Wait, `q.piggyback_sellable` is nil, so of course you get a no method error when you try to call something on it. If you try it on `p.piggyback_sellable` (i.e. `p.piggybak_sellable.update_attributes`) it should work, right? Why do you have `p` and `q`?

Comment: I was just trying to show the attributes available when u call `piggybak_sellable` on a product that has already been assigned values in the interface. I am just trying to do it manually on the command-line. `p` is a different product. I should clarify that in the question. I also added a link to the gem in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that what I need to do is to set the `piggybak_sellable` attribute of my product, to be equal to an instance of a `Piggybak::Sellable` class which can be done like this:

```
1.9.3p194 :006 > m.piggybak_sellable = Piggybak::Sellable.new({:sku => "YJ4567", :description => "Awesome tablet", :price => 399, :quantity => 50, :item_id => 20, :item_type => "Product", :active => true})
   (0.3ms)  begin transaction
  Piggybak::Sellable Exists (18.7ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "sellables" WHERE "sellables"."sku" = 'YJ4567' LIMIT 1
  SQL (29.6ms)  INSERT INTO "sellables" ("active", "description", "item_id", "item_type", "price", "quantity", "sku", "unlimited_inventory") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["active", true], ["description", "Awesome tablet"], ["item_id", 20], ["item_type", "Product"], ["price", #<BigDecimal:7fa97c8f29d8,'0.399E3',9(36)>], ["quantity", 50], ["sku", "YJ4567"], ["unlimited_inventory", false]]
   (2.7ms)  commit transaction
 => #<Piggybak::Sellable id: 3, sku: "YJ4567", description: "Awesome tablet", price: #<BigDecimal:7fa97cf2ec98,'0.399E3',9(36)>, quantity: 50, item_id: 20, item_type: "Product", active: true, unlimited_inventory: false>
```

Comment: using my corrected example you can have the benefit of using the update_attributes approach both for existing as for new records, in case you are not satisfied with your syntax.

Comment: I don't think the `build_piggybak_sellable` will work because I need to create a new instance of the class `Piggybak::Sellable`. So, given a "normal" association, I would agree with you.....but not in this case because of the new classes that the piggybak gem (which is a Rails engine) creates.

Comment: the build_piggybak_sellable will build the new instance, the subsequent update_attributes call will create (persist) it. From what I got from the question I thought this is what you wanted to achieve. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Update Attributes work if the object already exists as pointed by the error message you received.
Try something like this:

```
1.9.3p194 :008 > q.piggybak_sellable.create(:sku => "YJ4567", :description => "Awesome tablet", :price => 399, :quantity => 100, :item_id => 20, :item_type => "Product", :active => true)
```

Comment: Just tried that and got this: `1.9.3p194 :012 > q.piggybak_sellable.create(:sku => "YJ4567", :description => "Awesome tablet", :price => 399, :quantity => 50, :item_id => 20, :item_type => "Product", :active => true)
NoMethodError: undefined method 'create' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Sry, Didn't knew of the GEM thing.

Comment: Perfectly reasonable attempt though.

Answer (score 0):

As marcamillion already stated, your association clearly does not exist, at least in some cases. The question now is how could you let it initialize silently in order for it not to break when the association is not there. I would try to achieve it like this:

```
( q.piggybak_sellable || q.build_piggyback_sellable ).
update_attributes(:sku => "YJ4567", :description => "Awesome tablet", 
                  :price => 399, :quantity => 100, :item_id => 20, 
                  :item_type => "Product", :active => true)
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work either, because I need to create the object first. I tink I have a solution - I am going to test it. If it works, then I will add it as an answer.