# How do I keep two records, for different models, in sync without falling into the callback trap?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have attributes on two models that I would like to keep in sync.

```
1.9.3p194 :009 > p
 => #<Product id: 19, name: "Long Sleeve Blue", description: "<p>\tLong Sleeve Blue Flannel shirt comes in all siz...", price: 49.99, vendor_id: 12, created_at: "2012-12-15 23:35:05", updated_at: "2013-01-24 19:11:18", image: "shirt.png", sku: "ABC10034"> 
1.9.3p194 :010 > p.piggybak_sellable
 => #<Piggybak::Sellable id: 1, sku: "AR4590", description: "Blue Shirt", price: #<BigDecimal:7fa97cd63ff8,'0.2499E2',18(45)>, quantity: 100, item_id: 19, item_type: "Product", active: true, unlimited_inventory: false>
```

Both of those share some attributes that are similar.

I have the creation aspect down - once a new record is created, I simply do an `after_create`.

The issue is with the updating of the record.

If I call an `after_save` and do an `update_attributes` in the method called by the `after_save` it starts an infinite loop and crashes the app.

How do I achieve that - given that I want to update many columns?

I know one solution is to use `update_column` - but that just works with 1 column.

Thoughts?

Comment: I assume if they are sync'ed..... they have some type of association? Why not just reference the other model's attributes?

Comment: Because I am using a gem - piggybak - that sets up the association, but it's not as simple as a regular AR assocation, because the gem is actually a Rails Engine. I explored some stuff related to that here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517088/how-do-i-update-the-attributes-of-an-attribute-on-an-ar-model/14527839#14527839

Answer (score 1):

You could temporarily deactivate the callback on the other model in each of your `after_save` callbacks to avoid looping like this. For the details on doing this, see the second answer of this question [How to skip ActiveRecord callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342761/how-to-skip-activerecord-callbacks)

Would probably look something like this:

```
after_save :update_product

def update_product
  Product.skip_callback(:save, :after, :update_other)
  p = Product.find_by_whatever(self.whatever)
  p.update_attributes(:one => self.one, :two => self.two)
  Product.set_callback(:save, :after, :update_other)
end
```